# Can I specify what characters set the double-click selection boundary in GNOME Terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, unicode

When I double-click to select text in GNOME Terminal, the selection stops at spaces but continues over hyphens:

[image: spaces]

[image: hyphens]

Some of my filenames contain uncommon characters such as the [heavy teardrop-spoked asterisk](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/273d/) and are not selectable by double-clicking:

[image: unusual characters]

Is there a way to make double-click selection continue over these characters as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In "Edit > Profile Preferences > General", add the character to the "Select-by-word characters" box.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I didn't notice that.

Comment: Has anyone found a general way to do this GNOME-wide? Or are word-boundaries up to the developers of each application to define/redefine? Related question: http://superuser.com/q/650240/245597 .

Comment: At least since version 3.14, this option has disappeared. How can we do it now?

Comment: I tried `dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:{your-profile-id}/word-char-exceptions '@ms "-,.;/?%&#_=+@~·:"'` but all I get is `error: Could not connect: Connection refused`

Comment: Can't seem to get the non-breaking space to work. It does work with the funky asterisk on mate terminal from Zesty however.

Answer (score 20):

*[Adding an answer since the accepted one no longer works.]*

**Script**

I put this together into a script to set the word separators:

https://github.com/ab/ubuntu-wart-removal/blob/master/gnome-terminal-word-separators.sh

**Background**

GNOME Terminal has flip flopped several times on this subject.

This configuration feature was removed in gnome-terminal 3.14 (included in Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid)

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=727743
- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730632

Then in gnome-terminal 3.16 (included in Ubuntu 15.10 Wily), the option was reintroduced under the hood, but with no UI. In addition, colon `:` was changed to be treated as a word separator.

**Editing with dconf**

Per these instructions, you can configure the set using dconf: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1401207/comments/8

I like to use `-#%&+,./:=?@_~` as the set of non-word-separators.

> Note that the use of colons there is /crazy/. Yes, there is :/: in there.
>
> 1) edit -> profile preferences -> the General tab on your profile has its Profile ID, e.g. b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9
>
> 2) check you've got the syntax right with:
>
> $ `dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/
>   foreground-color
>   visible-name
>   palette
>   use-system-font
>   ...`
>
> If it returns nothing, you've got it wrong; try again.
>
> 3) `dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/word-char-exceptions '@ms "-#%&+,./:=?@_~"'`
>
> Specifically, this has ":" in, which makes it select URLs like I expect. (http://example.com doesn't select "//example.com").

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed in order to get `:`. Is it possible that you could write the command(s) to automatically fetch the default or current profile so I don't have to manually look up my profile ID in order to run that command in future? That way I can just run that script on fresh installs.

Comment: @Programster You could do something like this with `dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/`

Comment: thanks @alberge I took that and put it in a python script

Comment: What is the default value of `word-char-exceptions`, so I can add just one character?

Comment: @TorKlingberg Apparently no one knows.  You can use the dconf-editor graphical application to browse to that location.  All it says is "default", but not what the default value is.

Comment: Using dconf Editor works for me, but strangely, the Summary of the `word-char-exceptions` property seems to state that these characters will NOT be considered part of words: "List of ASCII punctuation characters that are not to be treated as part of a word when doing word-wise selection." However, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, I get the exact opposite behavior, i.e. specifying a value of `'_'` results in ONLY underscore (and alphanumeric characters) being part of words. Perhaps I just misunderstood the description of this property?

Comment: @jth I think you're right, the dconf schema's description of the property has it backwards. Normally gnome-terminal breaks words on punctuation, but the exceptions WILL be considered part of words.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers do not work today ... this works on ubuntu 18.04 ... first identify your UUID gnome terminal profile id ... issue this in terminal

```
profile=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default)

echo $profile  #  for me it gives b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d97969
```

now make change :

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d97969/word-char-exceptions '@ms "-,.;?%&#_+@~·$/"'
```

until ubuntu 18.04 gets fixed the following read command silently fails whereas it worked fine on ubuntu 16.04

```
dconf  read  /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/word-char-exceptions
```

Comment: Looks rather like https://askubuntu.com/a/725109/158442

Answer (score 0):

A very useful default feature implemented in other terminals is the progressive selection of extended sections of a line on the screen. e.g., given

```
/home/username/dir1_r.2-3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr 23456677 dftrprpr
```

double-clicking on, say, `filenr` in `dsr.filenr_34.ctr` would progress from `filenr` to:

```
                              filenr_34
                          dsr.filenr_34.ctr
                       -3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr
                      2-3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr
                    r.2-3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr
               dir1_r.2-3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr
      username/dir1_r.2-3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr
 home/username/dir1_r.2-3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr
 home/username/dir1_r.2-3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr 23456677
 home/username/dir1_r.2-3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr 23456677 dftrprpr
/home/username/dir1_r.2-3/dsr.filenr_34.ctr 23456677 dftrprpr
```

Surrounding symmetries may be solved by adding pairs until next-level delimiter.

And of course the user should be given the option of changing defaults.

Comment: No comment on the answer but try to format it in a better way so that people understand it faster. If you want to list it step by step, use numbering.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this applies to my question. I'm specifically asking how to configure GNOME Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @alberge answer, you can execute the following `python3` script to change all your profiles to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

command = ["dconf", "list", "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/"]
result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

profiles = result.stdout.split('\n')

for profileString in profiles:
    if profileString.startswith(":"):
        changeCmdPart = "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/" + profileString + "word-char-exceptions"
        changeCmd = ["dconf", "write", changeCmdPart, '@ms "-#%&+,./:=?@_~"']
        subprocess.run(changeCmd)

print("done!")
```

Or you can just execute:

```
curl -s http://scripts.programster.org/scripts/5?output=raw | python3
```

Answer (score 0):

At Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.
I've lost a couple of hours, trying to make it work. But the reason of the stall is quite simple: the meaning of "@ms" variable is inverse to intuitive, and inverse to what they've written in org.gnome.Terminal.gschema.xml.

@ms should contain the only characters, ALLOWED to select by double-click.
So, if you DON'T want dashes or colons or smth to select, you may enter:

```
UUID=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | tr -d \')
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${UUID}/word-char-exceptions "@ms '_^'"
```

Change works immediately, retains through reset; but for different profile, you should repeat the command.

Comment: Ubuntu 20 would be the Ubuntu Core 20 as that is the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version. If this is not the case please edit and correct the answer.

Comment: thanx, I've chaged