# What are "select-by-word" characters?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

What are the "select-by-word" in gnome-terminal's preferences?

Answer (score 12):

"Select-by-word" characters are those characters that define words. They are used to determine which characters to select when doing double clicks.

Eg., if you have `a-z@` in this list, a valid word would be `a@z`. If you then have a string like

`333a@z444`

and you make a double click over 'a', '@', or 'z', it will only select `a@z`, because '3' and '4' aren't valid word characters.

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8413/can-i-specify-what-characters-set-the-double-click-selection-boundary-in-gnome-te) for an example.

Comment: Has anyone found a general way to set these word boundaries GNOME-wide (i.e., not just in Terminal)? Or are they up to the developers of each GNOME application to define/redefine? Related question: http://superuser.com/q/650240/245597 .