# alternate double click for slash as delimiter

Tags: mouse, doubleclick

I'm using Bash in gnome-terminal in Ubuntu 16.04. Sometimes I want to double click and select one level of directory in a path, using slash as delimiter. I'd like to keep the default double click behaviour (e.g. select "/the/whole/path"), but for example Shift + double click would select one level of directory (e.g. "whole"). Is there such a plugin or script that implements this?

Comment: what program/tool are you referring to?

Comment: Bash in Ubuntu 16.04. I edited my question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: bash within gnome-terminal?

Comment: related # https://askubuntu.com/q/8413/631600