# How do I copy just the text inside double (") quotes and single (' apostrophe) quotes? (in xterm terminal)

Tags: window-manager, paste

If I have a string like "8383838" and I want just the digits part I can double click to get "8383838" but if I click randomly I sometimes get 8383838 without quotes.
I'd like to know what I'm doing to get that, but can't quite figure out how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior I've noted is that the `"` characters act as a boundary and are *not* included when double-clicking for a selection (though they *are* included when triple-clicking to grab the whole line) - I'm using stock settings.

In any case, (as you'd expect) you can change this behavior. From [Can I specify what characters set the double-click selection boundary in GNOME Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8413/can-i-specify-what-characters-set-the-double-click-selection-boundary-in-gnome-t):

1. In Terminal, go to **Edit** > **Profile Preferences** > **General**
2. Remove the `"` character from the **Select-by-word characters** box if you'd like to ensure it's considered part of double-click selections *or* ensure it appears if you'd prefer to treat it as a boundary
3. Save settings and test to confirm working

Comment: Ah interesting, I'm actually using urxvt (xterm-like) which is perhaps the place to look. I checked the standard terminal (I'm in ubuntu 18.04) and "select-by-word" wasn't there but since I asked this a while ago, perhaps it's changed.  Thanks Gray!