# double click on text in terminal selects beyond word boundary

Tags: gnome-terminal, dconf

Ubuntu 18.10  gnome terminal 3.30.1

In gnome terminal when I double click on below word `background` it only makes sense it should highlight only the word `background`

```
background=true
```

however it highlights `background=true`

other distros' terminal allows you to edit the set of chars to define a word boundary

I issue this to find my UUID

```
sudo dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

which shows

```
:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/
```

to view available attributes I issue

```
sudo dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

output :

```
[:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9]
default-size-rows=42
default-size-columns=142
use-transparent-background=true
use-theme-colors=false
use-theme-transparency=false
scrollback-unlimited=true
background-color='rgb(28,30,31)'
background-transparency-percent=3
audible-bell=false
```

below used to work in previous ubuntu releases to define attribute `word-char-exceptions`

```
sudo dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/word-char-exceptions '@ms "-#%&+,./:=?@_~"'
```

none of the answers here work on 18.10  [Can I specify what characters set the double-click selection boundary in GNOME Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8413/can-i-specify-what-characters-set-the-double-click-selection-boundary-in-gnome-t)

**UPDATE**  here is what works

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/ word-char-exceptions  '@ms "-,.?%&#_+@~·/"'
```

just replace `b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9` with your own UUID value

Comment: These commands should work, nothing changed here in the last couple of years in gnome-terminal. Remove all those `sudo`s, though! You should be fiddling with your own settings as a normal user, why switch to the superuser? Chances are that you're modifying the superuser's settings and not your own ones. Oh, and make sure to _remove_ the '=' sign from the list!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set it by below commands.
change the profile id with your profile id in the below command.
mine is `a565cffd-62b9-4c43-bd4e-d4b48b2c3cb4`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:a565cffd-62b9-4c43-bd4e-d4b48b2c3cb4/ word-char-exceptions '@ms "-,.?%&#_+@~·/"'
```

here is the example:

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList list
['b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9', 'a565cffd-62b9-4c43-bd4e-d4b48b2c3cb4']
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:a565cffd-62b9-4c43-bd4e-d4b48b2c3cb4/ word-char-exceptions
@ms nothing
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:a565cffd-62b9-4c43-bd4e-d4b48b2c3cb4/ word-char-exceptions '@ms "-,.?%&#_+@~·/"'
pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried your ! approach and was close yet here is what worked fine ...  `gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/ word-char-exceptions  '@ms "-,.?%&#_+@~·/"'`

Answer (score 1):

The dconf approach in case anyone tries it, no longer seems to work on ubuntu20 and maybe others. This worked for me:

```
UUID=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | tr -d \')
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${UUID}/ word-char-exceptions '@ms "-/@_&.?"'
```